# Use regex to transform height column into total inches column

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse

I am trying to "use regular expressions to use the height column to create a total_inches column that has the total height in inches and is recorded as a numeric variable.

I came up with a solution... but I don't think it fits the task...
(language is R)

```
bball_data$total_inches <- bball_data$height %>% 
  str_extract(regex("(^\\d+) (-) (\\d+$)", comments = TRUE))


bball_data <- bball_data %>% separate(total_inches, c("feet", "inches"), "-", convert = TRUE) %>%
    mutate(total_inches = (12*feet + inches))
```

The top line is essentially useless other than using the regex... it's been about 3 hours lol what am I missing?

*update...

```
bball_data$total_inches <- str_replace(bball_data$height,regex("(^\\d+)(-)(\\d+$)", comments = TRUE), "\\1+\\3")
```

this is getting me pretty close to the end result.. but as you may guess i am unable to add \1 to \3... i tried as.numeric and as.int... but neither work.. is there another way to add this replacement value?
dput output is ...

structure(list(name = c("Alaa Abdelnaby", "Zaid Abdul-Aziz",
"Kareem Abdul-Jabbar", "Mahmoud Abdul-Rauf", "Tariq Abdul-Wahad",
"Shareef Abdur-Rahim"),
year_start = c(1991L, 1969L, 1970L, 1991L,
1998L, 1997L),
year_end = c(1995L, 1978L, 1989L, 2001L, 2003L,
2008L),
position = c("F-C", "C-F", "C", "G", "F", "F"),
height = c("6-10",
"6-9", "7-2", "6-1", "6-6", "6-9"),
weight = c(240L, 235L, 225L,
162L, 223L, 225L),
birth_date = c("June 24, 1968", "April 7, 1946",
"April 16, 1947", "March 9, 1969", "November 3, 1974", "December 11, 1976"
),
college = c("Duke University", "Iowa State University", "University of California, Los Angeles",
"Louisiana State University", "San Jose State University", "University of California"
)),
row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It will help us if you [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a small representative dataset in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(bball_data)`, if that is not too large.

Comment: it's pretty large... but i'll try and make a smaller one to replicate. thanks!

Comment: `dput(head(bball))` will likely be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apologies for posting a poor question format... i'll do better next time...
here is the answer i came up with after about 5.5 hours!

```
bball_data$height <- str_extract_all(bball_data$height, "\\d+", simplify = TRUE)

bball_data$total_inches <- as.numeric(bball_data$height[,1])*12 + as.numeric(bball_data$height[,2])
```

this code will take the height then put it into a matrix. the 2nd line will take that value as.numeric and then compute the value i needed "total inches" and put it into a total_inches column within bball_data.